# How can I take the intersection of two geometries in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to take the intersection of two geometries in Silverlight (4.0)?

Background: in order to implement clipping, we need to take the current clipping area (a geometry) and intersect that with a new area in order to obtain the new clipping area.

We actually have a solution for this, but it seems awkward, or at least sub-optimal: we draw inside a canvas with its own clipping area, and whenever we need the intersection of a new clipping area, we create a new canvas with its own clipping area, and place that in the old one. We can then start drawing objects in the new canvas, and they will be correctly clipped against both.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "Composite geometries", check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189068%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to find how to create composite geometries.

Answer (score 0):

W.r.t. the answer of Andris: unfortunately, using composite geometries does not appear to be sufficient. A GeometryGroup creates a union of shapes. To my knowledge there is no way to specify an intersection.

Note also that the fill rules are too limited to specify an intersection.